# How to simulate low disk write speed in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, performance-testing, disk-io

I use dd command as follows, to check the disk speed of my ubuntu box:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=640M count=1 oflag=dsync
```

That gives me the actual disk speed. But how do I simulate a case of low disk write speed? I want to get a really bad speed of writing.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/q/13590/1186757 or https://serverfault.com/q/523509. I found both with google using search keywords "linux simulate slow disk".

Comment: Wow cool. I tried googling.  I used wrong keyword- induce low disk speed! Upvoting your comment!